# regarding Angular js ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

here below is my code . data are comeing from server side and this data,I want to show  in table form with the help of ng-repeat directive which is provided by angular js.

```
var app = angular.module('studentInfo', []);

app.controller('studentInfoController', function($scope,$http) {

    $scope.student ="";
    $scope.studentModel ="";
    $scope.submitStudentForm = function(isFormValid) {
        if(isFormValid){
            console.log("form valid")
            console.log($scope.student);
              $http({
                  method: 'POST',
                  url: 'school/studentinfo',
                  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                  data: {'studentInfo':$scope.student}
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                      $scope.studentModel = data;

                     console.log("student infor"+data);
                    // console.log("Student RollNumber:" +data.studentRollNo);
                    // console.log("Student Name:" +data.studentName);
                     //console.log('What is status here:' +status);
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                alert("Error Occured:"+status);
                            });


        } else if(!isFormValid) {
            console.log("Not valid")
            $scope.submitted = true;
            return;
        }
    };
});
```

in above all the data  are in this statement `$scope.studentModel = data;`

this is my jsp file and  in this file i want to show the data in table form

```
<table id="stuId" border="3 px">
    <tr>
        <th>StudentRollNo</th>
        <th>StudentName</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="studentInformation in studentModel" style="color: blue;">
        <label class="control-label">
            student information in school :{{studentModel.length}}
        </label>
        <td>
            {{studentInformation.studentRollNo}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{studentInformation.studentName}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the question? There is no problem statement here.

Comment: this code doesn't make sense.  You have some form you aren't showing here, and on success of the POST, you want to then iterate through the results?  POST is used to submit data to the server, not retrieve data;  beyond that, you haven't really even asked a question.

Comment: i want to send data from servlet to jsp using json obj.

Comment: this is my servlet code

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need else if condition, else is enough
- You cannot put a label inside a tr
- Initialize studentModel as array

  ```
  $scope.studentModel = [];
  ```
- If you want to listen to a change of the scope, use a $watch, here is an [example](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2658-using-scope-watch-to-watch-functions-in-angularjs.htm)